# What python deque-like containers retain valid iterators during mutation?

Tags: python, c++, iterator, deque

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107212/add-to-a-deque-being-iterated-in-python) that collections.deque is not a great choice if I want to retain valid iterators while mutating the data structure. Are there any data structures in python's stdlib that preserve valid iterators while supporting these two operations:

- append - Append something to the end of the container in O(1) amortized
- popleft - Pop something from the beginning of the container in O(1) amortized

### Why would I want something like this?

Consider a class that generates a stream of data. There are multiple consumers that call `__iter__` on this class to get an iterator to consume data in-order. For sake of simplicity, assume the `__iter__` calls happen before any `__next__` is called.

Suppose the stream is large enough that it could exceed reasonable memory limits. A reasonable thing to do is to use a deque, so that when an iterator is at the end of the deque, we block to wait for new data and `append` it. When all iterators have visited an element, we no longer need to keep it in memory, so we `popleft`.

The `std::deque` implementation in C++ uses circular list of buffers and allows us to have valid iterators upon these two operations. Is there something like this in python as well?

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) is designed for your use case exactly. Internally, it uses iterators pointing into a shared FIFO queue, but the data structure is internal to the `tee` implementation (which is written in C, at least in CPython).

You must pass the original iterable to `tee` exactly once, and never use it again. But you don't have to create all of the `tee` iterators up front; you can pass an existing iterator to `copy.copy` to get another that shares the same internal FIFO buffer.

Implementing a FIFO queue with iterators (your actual question) on top of `tee` would probably be possible, but it's tricky, in part because the iterator interface specifies that no more values can ever appear after `StopIteration` has been raised, while a typical FIFO can still be used after a failed pop.

Comment: The question states that the container should be modifiable, so this isn't really a good use case for `tee` - once the iterable has been split, it should not be used again. (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee))

Comment: @sj95126 I added a paragraph about correct usage.